# Multiple MySQL versions using Homebrew on macOS giving Error - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: mysql, macos

I am trying to set up multiple MySQL versions using Homebrew. I have already been using MySQL 8.*, which is running fine. However, due to some old project requirements today, I have installed another version of MySQL (5.7). Now when I switch to mysql@5.7, it gives me the following error.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

##### Please have a look at the following details

Both versions of MySQL are installed using **Homebrew**.

###### MySQL 8.* (latest) location

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.33/*
```

###### MySQL 5.7 location

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.42/*
```

Their symlinks are in `/usr/local/opt/*`

I have modified **homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist** as follows.

###### Original

```
...
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
        <string>--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var/mysql</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

###### Modified

```
...
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
        <string>--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql57</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var/mysql57</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

To switch between versions, I have set up an alias in `~/.zhsrc`

```
# MySQL Version Switching
mysqlv() {
    brew services stop mysql
    brew services stop mysql@5.7
    brew unlink mysql mysql@5.7
    brew link --force --overwrite $1
    brew services start $1
}

alias mysql57="mysqlv mysql@5.7"
alias mysql80="mysqlv mysql"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"
```

Later I set **password** for the **root** user to none with the following query.

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost='';
```

Now when I run the alias `mysql57`, it switches and links the MySQL version but when I try to login to `mysql -uroot` it gives below error.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
```

Can anyone help me to fix the issue so I can switch and use any version of MySQL